# How to loop between dates that are in dmy format

Tags: javascript, html, loops, date, datetime

Here is my 2 date

```
var startdate = '11-12-2016';
var stopdate = '13-12-2016';
```

I want to loop between these two dates. So, i did like this

```
var startMedicine = new Date(startdate);
var stopMedicine = new Date(stopdate);
while(startMedicine <= stopMedicine){
  console.log(startdate)
}
```

But i am getting unlimited loops running in browser.

How can i do this.

**Note :**

I don't want to use jQuery for this one.

If the start and end date is same it should loop only once and the input date will be always d/m/y format. What is the mistake in my code. Pls help

**Update :**

I have mistaken the date format,  my date format is d-m-y. How can i do this for one..

Comment: Have you considered to increase `startMedicine` in the body of the loop, by the amount of milliseconds in a day?

Comment: Ah, sorry.. shall i do startMedicine++ inside loop ?

Comment: That would increase only by one, you'd get unexpected long loop. Please re-read my comment above.

Comment: I tried by adding 86400, but it doesn't work, can you pls tel me how

Comment: 86400 is an hour only ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increment date by one day per iteration using `getDate`

```
startdateArr = startdate.split('-');
stopdateArr = stopdate.split('-');

var startMedicine = new Date(startdateArr[2],startdateArr[1]-1,startdateArr[0]);

var stopMedicine = new Date(stopdateArr[2],stopdateArr[1]-1,stopdateArr[0]);
// thanks RobG for correcting on month index
while(startMedicine <= stopMedicine){
  var v  = startMedicine.getDate() + '-' + (startMedicine.getMonth() + 1) + '-' +   startMedicine.getFullYear();
  console.log(v);
  startMedicine.setDate(startMedicine.getDate()+1);
}
```

In js month indexing starts at 0 so nov is 10 dec. is 11 and like so  that's why i use `getMonth() + 1`
`

Comment: Thanks it works good, Can you pls tell if the dates are in d-m-y format

Comment: Pls, see the update in the question. can you do according to that pls

Comment: No they are in native js form printing them converts it to usual Sat Nov 12 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (JST) but you can convert them as you like if u want i can show you

Comment: Yes, pls show me how to convert them too. it would be helpful

Comment: Hi, thanks, created a fiddle, but it doesn't output any result.. https://jsfiddle.net/5r4L4gyo/

Comment: Hmm coz js doesn't accept that formatbut no worry i will show a workaround

Comment: Try now , update splits parts of date and passes to [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor with adjusted position of parameters

Comment: @RobG Oops :p .Thanx for correcting. user3432407 apologies plz see the update

Answer (score 0):

main problem is that you are not increasing your date.

here is the solution

```
var startdate = '11/12/2016';
var stopdate  = '11/13/2016';

var startMedicine = new Date(startdate);
var stopMedicine = new Date(stopdate);

var currentMedicine = startMedicine;
var dayCount = 0;

while(currentMedicine < stopMedicine){
  currentMedicine.setDate(startMedicine.getDate() + dayCount);

  // You can replace '/' to '-' this if you want to have dd-mm-yyyy instead of dd/mm/yyy
  var currentDate = currentMedicine.getDate() + '/' + (currentMedicine.getMonth() + 1) + '/' +  currentMedicine.getFullYear(); // in dd/mm/yyyy format

  console.log(currentDate);

  dayCount++;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you pls update the answer according to the date format d-m-y

Comment: Do not parse dates with the Date constructor (or Date.parse), far better to split the string and pass the parts as arguments to the Date constructor (i.e. parse it manually). A library can help, but for a single format it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of moment js and moment js duration. Its for duration purpose only. It very easy and  meant for same.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.